# Negative Conditional Statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax, conditional-statements

It seems like the RubyMine IDE signals a warning whenever it sees a negative conditional statement. I am wondering why using negative conditional statement is bad? Is it just purely due to readability?

For example, in this code:

```
class Complement
    def self.of_dna dna_strand
      dna_array =  dna_strand.chars
      dna_complement  = ['']
      dna_structure = ['C', 'G', 'T', 'A']

      dna_array.each do |strand|
        unless dna_structure.include? strand 
          return ''
        end

        case strand
        when "C"
         dna_complement << "G"
        when "G"
         dna_complement << "C"
        when "T"
         dna_complement << "A"
        when "A"
         dna_complement << "U"
        end
      end
    dna_complement.join('')
  end
end
```

I am wondering what is the different between `unless dna_structure.include? strand` and `if !(dna_strucutre.include?)` in this case?

Comment: You could write your `case` statement `dna_complement <<  case strand; when "C" then "G"; when "G" then "C"; when "T" then "A"; when "A" then "U"; end`. Alternatively, you could write `dna_complement << strand.tr("CGTA", "GCAU")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Ruby has not just `if`, but `unless`, you're encouraged to use it so long as the resulting code is clear. That is you should convert something like this:

```
if (!string.empty?)
  # ...
end
```

Into something like this:

```
unless (string.empty?)
  # ...
end
```

There's exceptions to this, like when you have this:

```
if (!string.empty?)
  # ... when not empty
else
  # ... when empty (when not not empty)
end
```

The naive approach would be to convert that to an `unless` but that creates a triple negative. You're already dealing with a double here, the `else` clause only happens if the string is *not not* empty, or arguably *does not not not contain anything*.

Do this instead:

```
if (string.empty?)
  # ... when empty
else
  # ... when not empty
end
```

There's a number of problems with the approach you're taking here, but the most grievous is that you're declaring a constant array inside your method each time the method is invoked. Since that never changes make it a constant at the top of the class level. At least:

```
class Complement
  DNA_STRUCTURE = %w[ C G A T ]
end
```

Even better would be to use a mapping table to represent the pairings:

```
COMPLEMENT = {
  'C' => 'G',
  'G' => 'C',
  'T' => 'A',
  'A' => 'U'
}.freeze
```

Now looking at your particular problem where you're trying to "invert" a given strand of characters, the tool you really want is [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-tr) on the string itself, a method that's optimized for handling things like cyphers where there's a 1:1 mapping between characters.

Your entire function collapses to this:

```
def self.of_dna(strand)
  strand.tr('CGTA', 'GCAU')
end
```

Now if you want to do a quick test to ensure you're actually dealing with a valid sequence:

```
def self.of_dna(strand)
  return '' unless (strand.match(/\A[CGTA]*\z/))

  strand.tr('CGTA', 'GCAU')
end
```

There's some other bad habits you're getting into here, like creating arrays to hold single characters when strings are much better at that particular task. `c = ''` and then `c << 'G'` would be more efficient than an array version of same, especially considering the array will hold N strings, each of which carries some overhead, and requires creating *another* string at the end using `join`. When using Ruby try and keep the number of objects required to do your computation, temporary or otherwise, to a minimum. It's usually faster with less "garbage".

Comment: your response is doubleplusgood for showing an alternative to the case statement!

Comment: @tadman Wow, thank you so much. Not only you answered my question but you also gave a lot of valuable advice. I will refactor my code now.

Comment: @tadman Could you also please explain the regex to me? I don't understand what `\A` and `\z` means in the beginning and in the end of the regex.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with regular expressions check out a site like [Rubular](http://rubular.com) for explanations and an easy way to run tests.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the latter form but considering in ruby we have `unless` we should use it when we have just one branch and it's preferable, as in this case.

Anyway, it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's horses for courses... I've worked with very good developers whose first language isn't English and they find the `If !` (if not) easier to comprehend.

But the Ruby style guide https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide specifically prefers `unless` to `if !` but frowns upon `unless` being used with `else`.

Finally it's better to rewrite as a single-line with trailing conditional...

```
    return '' unless dna_structure.include? strand
```